# wget cant file file after download - IPV6 ONLY debian server

Tags: bash, debian, wget

I am issuing wget commands within a bash script and while it says everything went fine, I can't find the files!

I have a directory structure like so:

```
/home/foo/.x/.y
```

and in `/home/foo/.x`, I have the bash script `xy.sh`, with contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/foo/.x/.y
echo "Start job at: $(date)" >> /home/foo/.log.log
URL1="http://xyz1.com/11.csv.zip"
URL2="http://xyz2.com/111.csv.zip"
URL3="http://xyz3.com/1111.csv.zip"
URL4="http://xyz4.com/11111.csv.zip"
URL5="http://xyz5.com/111111.csv.zip"
URL6="http://xyz6.com/1111111.csv.zip"
URL7="http://xyz7.com/11111111.zip"
wget -q "${URL1}"
echo " job 1 done: $(date)" >> /home/foo/.log.log
wget -q "${URL2}"
echo "job 2 done at: $(date)" >> /home/foo/.log.log
wget -q "${URL3}"
echo " job 3 done at: $(date)" >> /home/foo/.log.log
wget -q "${URL4}"
echo " job 4 done at: $(date)" >> /home/foo/.log.log
wget -q "${URL5}"
echo " job 5 done at: $(date)" >> /home/foo/.log.log
wget -q  "${URL6}"
echo " job 6 done at: $(date)" >> /home/foo/.log.log
wget -q "${URL7}"
echo "End job at: $(date)" >> /home/foo/.log.log
exit 0
```

The log indicates the files have been downloaded but I can't find the files in `/home/foo/.x/.y`

PS: when I download the files with wget normally (without bash scripting) the files download fine..

FYI: the server is a IPV6 only server..

Comment: Why not use the -O option for wget and specify where the files should end up?

Answer (score 1):

In your script you have just a sequence of commands without a logiccal dependency. For example after retrieving the URL1 the message is displayed even if the wget fails.
try replacing this:

```
wget -q "${URL1}"
echo " job 1 done: $(date)" >> /home/foo/.log.log
```

with this:

```
wget -q "${URL1}" \
    && echo " job 1 done: $(date)" >> /home/foo/.log.log \
    || echo " job 1 Failed $(date)" >> /home/foo/.log.log \
```

the "&&" and "||" are used to conditionally execute the "echo" commands. If the wget is successfull, then "done", otherwise "failed".
Because you use the "-q" option for wget you will not see the reason why it fails, so until you figure out the failure I suggest removing the '-q' so you could see the output, like this:

```
wget "${URL1}" >> /home/foo/.log.log 2>&1 \
    && echo " job 1 done: $(date)" >> /home/foo/.log.log \
    || echo " job 1 Failed $(date)" >> /home/foo/.log.log \
```

all info will be stored in the log.

Comment: I will try this now but I fail to understand why wget is doing the `job` (I know this from the times on my logs) but not saving the file? This is VERy weird!

Comment: if wget works you should have the files in `/home/foo/.x/.y` directory. If wget doesn't work you should have some reason the the log.

Comment: your trouble shooting was correct.. it just does not download.. my VPS is an IPv6 only server.. does this affect the download?

Comment: Based on the manual page it shouldn't. Since it's working when you download manually then it should by script to, if you are running it under the same user and don't have any special .wgetrc configuration or maybe some proxy settings under your normal user environment that doesn't exist when the script is executed. If you can't find it, try using wget with  "-6" option in the script to force the IPv6 download. But I would recommend to do some research based on the error message you got from wget in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Does /home/foo/.x/.y exist?

What happens if you remove the -q option from wget?

For the sake of troubleshooting I'd suggest adding "set -ueo" below the #!/bin/bash shebang - this will give you a much clearer indication of where the problem lies.